# Are Result objects the cleaner way to handle failure, than exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception, design-patterns, architecture, design-guidelines

> I moved this question to [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/394790/are-result-objects-the-cleaner-way-to-handle-failure-then-exceptions) because it better fits there.

I was watching the following video by Vladimir Khorikov, which recommends to *"Refactoring Away from Exceptions"* [pluralsight.com - Applying Functional Principles in C# - Refactoring Away from Exceptions](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=csharp-applying-functional-principles&author=vladimir-khorikov&name=csharp-applying-functional-principles-m3&clip=0&mode=live) and instead using a Result object. You can also find a blog about it here: [enterprisecraftsmanship.com - Functional C#: Handling failures, input errors](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/20/functional-c-handling-failures-input-errors/)

To summarize it, the recommendation is to prefer returning a result object then throwing an exception. Exceptions should be used to signalize a bug only.
The arguments for this approach are the following:

- Methods which throws exceptions are not "honest". You can't recognize if a method is expected to fail or not, by looking at its signature.
- Exception handling adds a lot of boiler plate code.
- When exceptions are used to control the flow, it has a "goto" semantic, where you can jump to specific line of code.

On the other hand return values can be ignored (at least in C#), which exceptions can not.

**Is it a good idea to refactor a existing enterprise application in this direction? Or is a less radical approach the better one?** (I belive that it make sense for sure to avoid [Vexing exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) by using return types for method like `ValidateUserInput(string input)`)

Comment: These are great questions, but the only answers would be opinions. This would be a better question for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I moved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060968/are-result-objects-the-cleaner-way-to-handle-failure-then-exceptions